Flutter blue plus not working as expected
I am implementing the Bluetooth feature into my app. I am able to scan the on bluetooth devices and show them on screen. and when I turned off the device, it removed the device from the list and did not display on the screen. but while doing so, it shows the scanningForDeviceText(), After 5 seconds, it disappeared, then again displayed devices, then again this text.my devices list not display stable. After every 5 seconds, it scans, it becomes zero, and it goes to my else condition How can i tackle this.
Here is my code:
 super.initState();
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog(context: context);
    flutterBlue = FlutterBluePlus();
    _adapterStateStateSubscription =
        FlutterBluePlus.adapterState.listen((state) {
      _adapterState = state;
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {});
      }
          _handleBluetoothStateChange();
    });
    _setupBluetoothSubscriptions();
      startContinuousScan();
     @override
    void dispose() {
    _adapterStateStateSubscription.cancel();
    _scanResultsSubscription.cancel();
    _isScanningSubscription.cancel();
      FlutterBluePlus.stopScan();  // Stop scanning when disposing
    super.dispose();
     }

      void _handleBluetoothStateChange() {
     if (_adapterState != BluetoothAdapterState.on) {
    setState(() {
      scanResults.clear();  // Clear scan results when Bluetooth is off
    });
  }
  _checkBluetoothPermission();
}

Future startContinuousScan() async {
  while (true) {
    try {
      int divisor = Platform.isAndroid ? 8 : 1;
      await FlutterBluePlus.startScan(
          timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
          continuousUpdates: true,
          continuousDivisor: divisor);
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
      await FlutterBluePlus.stopScan();
    } catch (e) {
      // customToastMessage(toastMessage: e.toString());
       }
        }
     }
    void _setupBluetoothSubscriptions() {
    _scanResultsSubscription = FlutterBluePlus.scanResults.listen((results) {
      scanResults = results;
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {});
      }
    }, onError: (e) {});

    _isScanningSubscription = FlutterBluePlus.isScanning.listen((state) {
      isScanning = state;
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {});
      }
    });
  }
scanResults.isNotEmpty
                                  ? SizedBox(
                                    height: 300,
                                    child: ListView.builder(
                                        itemCount: scanResults.length,
                                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                          final result = scanResults[index];
                                          if (result.device.name.startsWith("NT") ||
                                              result.device.name.startsWith("TW")) {
                                            return ListTile(
                                              onTap: () async {
                                                await _checkLocationPermission();
                                                if (doctorLinkedDeviceIdList.contains(result.device.name) ||
                                                doctorLinkedDeviceIdList.contains("*")) {
                                              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/NadiDisplayScreen', arguments: {
                                                'device': result.device,
                                                'patientDetails': patientDetails,
                                                'medicalId': medicalId,
                                                'appointmentForPatient': appointmentForPatient,
                                              });
                                            } else {
                                              showDialog(
                                                barrierDismissible: false,
                                                context: context,
                                                builder: (_) => CustomAlertDialog(
                                                  content: SizedBox(
                                                    width: 310.0,
                                                    height: 220.0,
                                                    child: Column(
                                                      children: [
                                                        Center(
                                                          child: Image.asset(
                                                            'assets/logos/linke_device.gif',
                                                            width: 84.0,
                                                            height: 84.0,
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                        const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                                                        Text(
                                                          "Select linked device.",
                                                          style: (screenWidth > 600) ? TabPopupMainTextStyle() : PopupMainTextStyle(),
                                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                        ),
                                                        const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                                                        Text(
                                                          "${result.device.name} is not linked with you.",
                                                          style: (screenWidth > 600) ? TabPopupSubTextStyle() : PopupSubTextStyle(),
                                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                        ),
                                                        Text(
                                                          "Select linked device & take nadi.",
                                                          style: (screenWidth > 600) ? TabPopupSubTextStyle() : PopupSubTextStyle(),
                                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              );
                                              Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
                                                Navigator.pop(context);
                                              });
                                            }
                                          },
                                          leading: Image.asset(
                                            'assets/bottom_navbar_icon/nadi.png',
                                            width: 40.0,
                                            height: 40.0,
                                            color: ColorConstants.textgreen,
                                          ),
                                          title: Text(
                                            result.device.name,
                                            style: (screenWidth > 600)
                                                ? TabDeviceNameForNadiPariksha()
                                                : DeviceNameForNadiPariksha(),
                                          ),
                                          subtitle: Flex(
                                            direction: Axis.horizontal,
                                            children: [
                                              Expanded(
                                                flex: 1,
                                                child: Text(
                                                  result.device.id.toString(),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      } else {
                                        return Container();
                                      }
                                    },
                                  ),
                              )
                              : scanningForDeviceText(),


i compressed my GIF so ignore the clarity
